# Insert icon only if variable value is true

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-directives

I have a database in which returns some values for me:

- `id`   : *integer*
- `nome`  : *string*
- `status`: *boolean*

I would like to show the item only if the value of the `status` variable is `true`.

See my **HTML**:

```html
<ion-list ion-item *ngFor="let item of itens">    
    <ion-item >  
      <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark" color="secondary" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This way above show the icon for all items.

How can do I insert the icon only if the value of the `status` variable is `true`?

Comment: Using *ngIf. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [***ngIf**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) *directive*:

```
<ion-icon name="checkmark" color="secondary" item-right *ngIf="item.status"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Thank u very much! hugs o/